# Replace do SQL SERVER entre colunas

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

Como fazer um replace entre colunas no SQL SERVER. Por exemplo, dado a tabela abaixo:

```
COLUNA_A | COLUNA B | COLUNA_C
A          123        casa
```

Tentei executar a consulta:

```
SELECT REPLACE(COLUNA_C, COLUNA_A, COLUNA_B ) FROM TABELA
```

Para tentar obter o resultado:

```
COLUNA_A | COLUNA B | COLUNA_C
A          123        c123s123
```

Mas não funcionou. Como posso fazer este replace utilizando os valores das colunas?

Se fizer assim:

```
SELECT REPLACE(COLUNA_C, 'a', COLUNA_B ) FROM TABELA
```

funciona normalmente. Inclusive eu tentei usar um cast ou convert em COLUNA_A E COLUNA_B, dentro do replace, também sem sucesso.

Comment: O que significa "não funcionou"? Como estão declaradas as colunas? Qual o COLLATE delas?

Comment: @JoséDiz Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: @JoséDiz Não altera nada. A consulta executa, e com replace mostra a mesma coisa sem o replace. O retorno fica assim:
COLUNA_A | COLUNA B | COLUNA_C (replace)
A                    123               casa

Comment: **(1)** É preciso analisar o COLLATE individual de cada coluna. O banco de dados pode estar em um COLLATE, a instância em outro COLLATE e cada coluna em outros COLLATE... **(2)** É certo que na coluna `coluna_A` existe somente um caractere? Cuidado com espaços e caracteres não visíveis.

Comment: Não foi o collate, mas foram os espaços e caracteres invisíveis. Daí só foi fazer REPLACE(COLUNA_C, LTRIM(RTRIM(COLUNA_A), COLUNA_B) e problema foi resolvido.

Comment: Malditos espaços...    ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A construção com a função REPLACE() está correta. Se não funcionou, uma hipótese é que as colunas estejam definidas com agrupamento *case sensitive*.  Se for este o caso, `A` é diferente de `a`.

Para avaliar se o motivo é agrupamento *case sensitive*, experimente:

```
-- código #1 v2
IF Object_ID('TABELA','U') is not null
  DROP TABLE dbo.TABELA;
go

CREATE TABLE dbo.TABELA (
     coluna_A varchar(20) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS, 
     coluna_B varchar(20) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS, 
     coluna_C varchar(20) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
);

INSERT into dbo.TABELA (coluna_A, coluna_B, coluna_C) values
  ('A', '123', 'casa_X'),
  ('a', '123', 'casa_Y');

SELECT replace (coluna_C, coluna_A, coluna_B)
  from dbo.TABELA;

SELECT replace (coluna_C collate Latin1_General_CI_AS, coluna_A, coluna_B)
  from dbo.TABELA;
```

Não testei o código #1, após a modificação. Pode conter erro(s).

Comment: Tentei sua solução, sem resultado. Ainda assim muito obrigado. Não é case sensitive.

Comment: Sei que não é case sensitive, porque fiz uma consulta teste aqui como os mesmos valores em ambas colunas, mas o replace não executa como esperado. Só executa se eu colocar um string manual (por exemplo: 'A' ou 'a') no segundo parâmetro, porém eu queria que a mudança fosse dinâmica.

Comment: Pose ser o tamanho da "coluna_a" 'a' é diferente de 'a     ' .